# R- Create a dataframe from lists of data that are not all the same length

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes that I would like to turn into a single dataframe.
Here is a subset of my data:

```
    date <- c("4/10/2016","4/11/2016","4/12/2016")
    time <- c("1:00:00 AM","1:15:00 AM", "1:30:00 AM")
    temp <- c(86.1,85.3,85.7)
    humidity <- c(39.9,39.5,39.1)
    object <- data.frame(date, time, temp, humidity)

    date2 <- c("4/10/2016","4/11/2016","4/12/2016","4/13/2016")
    time2 <- c("1:00:00 AM","1:15:00 AM","1:30:00 AM","1:45:00 AM")
    temp2 <- c(86.1,85.3,85.7,86.2)
    humidity2 <- c(39.9,39.5,39.1,40.0)
    object2 <- data.frame(date2, time2, temp2, humidity2)

    data1 <- list(object, object2)
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
   id     date        time temp humidity temp2 humidity2
    1 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9  86.1      39.9
    2 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5  85.3      39.5
    3 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1  85.7      39.1
    4 4/13/2016 1:45:00 AM   NA       NA  86.2      40.0
```

Because the dataframes are different lengths, I have not been successful at putting them together in a single dataframe. I tried padding the dataframes with NAs but was unsuccessful. I ended up adding new columns with NAs. I am new to coding so any explanations would be helpful. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my question.

**Update:**
Here is my data with one sensor starting after the others started.

```
    date <- c("4/10/2016","4/11/2016","4/12/2016")
    time <- c("1:00:00 AM","1:15:00 AM", "1:30:00 AM")
    temp <- c(86.1,85.3,85.7)
    humidity <- c(39.9,39.5,39.1)
    object <- data.frame(date, time, temp, humidity)

    date <- c("4/10/2016","4/11/2016","4/12/2016","4/13/2016")
    time <- c("1:00:00 AM","1:15:00 AM","1:30:00 AM","1:45:00 AM")
    temp2 <- c(86.1,85.3,85.7,86.2)
    humidity2 <- c(39.9,39.5,39.1,40.0)
    object2 <- data.frame(date, time, temp2, humidity2)

    date <- c("4/10/2016","4/11/2016","4/12/2016","4/13/2016")
    time <- c("1:00:00 AM","1:15:00 AM","1:30:00 AM","1:45:00 AM")
    temp3 <- c(NA,84.3,84.7,85.2)
    humidity3 <- c(NA,40.1,39.7,40.5)
    object3 <- data.frame(date, time, temp3, humidity3)

    data1 <- list(object, object2, object3)
```

And here's what I want it to look like:

```
   id     date        time temp humidity temp2 humidity2 temp3 humidity3
    1 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9  86.1      39.9    NA        NA
    2 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5  85.3      39.5  84.3      40.1
    3 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1  85.7      39.1  84.7      39.7
    4 4/13/2016 1:45:00 AM   NA       NA  86.2      40.0  85.2      40.5
```

Comment: I think `rbind` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Or `merge` ? It's not clear what you want as a result, maybe `merge(object, object2, by.x=c("date","time"), by.y=c("date2","time2"), all=TRUE)`

Comment: rbind is turning it into a matrix. I followed with as.data.frame, but it turned my data in an incoherent mess.

Comment: @thelatemail: in reality I have 20 dataframes in the list making merge impossible to use (as far as I can tell). I would like a single dataframe with the date and time followed by the temp and humidity from each "dataframe".

Comment: Using `dplyr` and `purrr`, `data1 %>% map(setNames, names(data1[[1]])) %>% bind_rows() %>% distinct()` or the base equivalent `unique(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(data1, setNames, names(data1[[1]]))))` ...though both make some assumptions about what you want.

Comment: Or to get the result specified, `data1 %>% map(~setNames(.x, c(names(data1[[1]])[1:2], names(.x)[3:4]))) %>% reduce(full_join)`

Comment: @alistaire `data1 %>% map(~setNames(.x, c(names(data1[[1]])[1:2], names(.x)[3:4]))) %>% reduce(full_join)` works great! I have one follow up question. One of my sensors didn't get started until 10:30 am rather than 1:00 am like the rest. Even though I added NAs at the beginning to fill in the missing data, it is not lining up with the rest of data. Is there any way I can address this? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have columns for those sensors in all the data.frames? If so, you can adjust the indices in `names(.x)[3:4]` to however many columns you have, or if you have varying columns, maybe `names(.x)[-1:-2]`. Most of the difficulty here is getting the names in the correct format for joining, where common columns are named the same thing. If you can fix that issue earlier in the data stream, it all simplifies down to `data1 %>% reduce(full_join)`.

Comment: @alistaire see my update for what the start looks like. `data1 %>% reduce(full_join)` also worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @alistaire `data1 %>% reduce(full_join)` is working on the updated example I created but not on my actual data. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `rbind` list elements together, you first need to have the names of the columns of each list elements to be the same.

```
names(data1[[2]]) <- names(data1[[1]])
```

(However, be careful here that the names of the columns are in the correct order.)

Then use `do.call(rbind, data1)`

```
do.call(rbind, data1)
#       date       time temp humidity
# 1 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9
# 2 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5
# 3 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1
# 4 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9
# 5 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5
# 6 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1
# 7 4/13/2016 1:45:00 AM 86.2     40.0
```

The pacakge `data.table` has an `rbindlist` function, that rbinds list elements. As you have different column names, you can either specify `use.names=T` & `fill=T`, so that it will pad with NAs where column names don't match. Or, leave `use.names = F`, in which icase it will use the order of the columns and assume they are the same

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(data1)
#         date       time temp humidity
# 1: 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9
# 2: 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5
# 3: 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1
# 4: 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9
# 5: 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5
# 6: 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1
# 7: 4/13/2016 1:45:00 AM 86.2     40.0

rbindlist(data1, use.names = T, fill = T)
#               date       time temp humidity     date2      time2 temp2 humidity2
# 1: 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9        NA         NA    NA        NA
# 2: 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5        NA         NA    NA        NA
# 3: 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1        NA         NA    NA        NA
# 4:        NA         NA   NA       NA 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM  86.1      39.9
# 5:        NA         NA   NA       NA 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM  85.3      39.5
# 6:        NA         NA   NA       NA 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM  85.7      39.1
# 7:        NA         NA   NA       NA 4/13/2016 1:45:00 AM  86.2      40.0
```

If you're looking to do a `SQL`-type join, you use `merge` (in base R)

```
merge(data1[[1]], data1[[2]], by.x = c("date","time","temp","humidity"), 
                              by.y = c("date2","time2","temp2","humidity2"), all = T)

#        date       time temp humidity
# 1 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9
# 2 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5
# 3 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1
# 4 4/13/2016 1:45:00 AM 86.2     40.0
```

**Update**

Based on your edit, you're after a right-join, so use `merge` with `all.y = T`

```
    merge(data1[[1]], data1[[2]], by.x = c("date"), by.y = c("date2"), all.y = T)
#         date       time temp humidity      time2 temp2 humidity2
# 1 4/10/2016 1:00:00 AM 86.1     39.9 1:00:00 AM  86.1      39.9
# 2 4/11/2016 1:15:00 AM 85.3     39.5 1:15:00 AM  85.3      39.5
# 3 4/12/2016 1:30:00 AM 85.7     39.1 1:30:00 AM  85.7      39.1
# 4 4/13/2016       <NA>   NA       NA 1:45:00 AM  86.2      40.0
```

Comment: Regarding `rbindlist`, I guess `dcast(rbindlist(data1, idcol=TRUE), date+time ~ .id, value.var=c("temp","humidity"))` looks more standard.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks for the update. In reality, my data has many more dataframes (something I probably should have said up front) making merge impossible to use as far as I can tell.